# Labeling polygons with the number of related table entries in QGIS

Tags: labeling, qgis-3, relates, aggregation

Using QGIS 3.6.1 I have a layer with areas and a table with entries related to the areas:

[image]

A relation is defined like this:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is to label the areas with the number of related table entries using `relation_aggregate` function as shown here:

[image]

```
relation_aggregate ('my_relation', 'count', 'text') || ' Table entries'
```

As can be seen in the screenshot (Output preview), the label expression delivers a valid result as expected (e.g. "4 Table Entries"), but labels are not shown in the map:

[image]

Another thing I tried using the `aggregate` function is the following:

[image]

```
with_variable('my_id', "id", aggregate('table', 'count', 'id', "flaeche_id" = @my_id)) || ' Table Entries'
```

Which gives a totally weird result depending on which area is shown in the current map extent, i.e.

1) Both areas labelled with "4 Table entries", but the lower *has only one related table entry* (see table above):

[image]

2) If the map extents only to the southernmost area, the label shows correctly "1 Table entries":

[image]

So all in all with my first approach I have *no* labels and with the second approach I have *wrong* labels.

I think I'm little stuck with the `aggregate...` functions in QGIS 3, am I using them the wrong way or are there any other approaches to the labeling I want to achieve?

Comment: did you try eval(relation_aggregate ('my_relation', 'count', 'text') || ' Table entries')?

Comment: just did so, same result either. no labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to double quote (") your last argument:

```
relation_aggregate('my_relation', 'count', "text") || ' Table entries'
```

the description of relation_aggregate says:

> relation_aggregate(relation,aggregate,expression[,concatenator])
>
> [ ] marks optional components

So if you just want to use a fieldname as expresion, you have to refer to it as "my_attribute", which is also standard in other expressions.

Somehow, the fieldcalulator returns a result when using a single quote ('), bizar ...